# How to view the entire content of an XML object while debugging in eclipse?

Tags: xml, eclipse

While debugging through eclipse, I am able to view only some lines of the XML object I constructed and it ends with .... although it has more contents which is not shown. Is there any way to view the entire XML object during debugging?

Note : I am not persisting this XML object. so cannot view from any table in DB.

Comment: What type is this "object"?

Comment: Its a string object. I tried to output the object to console as in System.out.print(objectXML); but still it is not displaying the entire contents.

Comment: In Eclipse->Windows->Preferences->Console, I unchecked the 'Limit Console Output' option which printed the entire xml output to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Debug -> Detail Formatters.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7163U.png)

Hit 'Add' to select a class.

Write a code snippet and put it in the Detail Formatter Code box.

As an example, for class org.jdom.Document  I used the snippet:

`new org.jdom.output.XMLOutputter().outputString(this);`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWA9X.png)